# How do I determine the file system of a volume in compact framework?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

Specifically, I need to determine whether a mounted SDIO card is using FAT or TFAT.

Win CE 5, CF 3.5

Comment: Not familiar with those frameworks but if they support WMI, that is a possibility. Some examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394592(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but Win CE does not contain WMI.  The equivalent call in the framework proper is DiskInfo.  This doesn't exist in compact framework, but presumably there is a P/Invoke call that can be made that someone can enlighten me about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not specifically tested this, but my bet is it's going to be a succession of P/Invokes to [`OpenStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891421.aspx), [`OpenPartition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891420.aspx) and [`GetPartitionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms890985.aspx)